# How to disable jinja2 in the Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to disable **Jinja2** in the *Flask*. How can I do it?
I have simple Flask project with Vue.js

Comment: Can yo post what you have tried so far?

Comment: If you don't use `render_template`, where will Jinja2 be used?

Comment: @Blender how I can return text from html file without render_template?
return "<html> ...</html>"?

Comment: @NinjaCoder sorry, I can't it(

Comment: Why? Have you not tried anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for Flask-RESTful? Which focuses on the API and doesn't have templating. https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/